# How to add new products in adapter in Android Studio with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am doing a project in Android Studio with Kotlin, I am new to this technology.

My app has a catalog of doors, I got everything working fine for one model, but now my query is how do I add the same functionality for new models, I have to copy and paste all the code changing the names?

I attach my catalog class:
package com.example.puertasarseapp

```
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore

class Catalogue : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var firestore: FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var puertasCollection: CollectionReference
    private lateinit var carritoCollection: CollectionReference
    private lateinit var puertasAdapter: PuertasAdapter
    private lateinit var puertasList: MutableList<Puerta>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalogue)

        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        puertasCollection = firestore.collection("puertas")
        carritoCollection = firestore.collection("carrito")
        puertasList = mutableListOf()

        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        puertasAdapter = PuertasAdapter(puertasList)
        recyclerView.adapter = puertasAdapter

        obtenerPuertas()

        puertasAdapter.setOnAddToCartClickListener(object :
            PuertasAdapter.OnAddToCartClickListener {
            override fun onAddToCartClick(
                puerta: Puerta,
                formatoSeleccionado: String?,
                medidasHojaSeleccionadas: String?,
                medidasBlockSeleccionadas: String?,
                aperturaSeleccionada: String?
            ) {
                guardarProductoEnFirestore(
                    puerta,
                    formatoSeleccionado,
                    medidasHojaSeleccionadas,
                    medidasBlockSeleccionadas,
                    aperturaSeleccionada
                )
            }
        })
    }

    private fun obtenerPuertas() {
        puertasCollection.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                puertasList.clear()
                for (document in result) {
                    val puerta = document.toObject(Puerta::class.java)
                    puertasList.add(puerta)
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "Puertas obtenidas: $puertasList")
                puertasAdapter.actualizarPuertas(puertasList)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.e(TAG, "Error al obtener las puertas: $exception")
            }
    }

    private fun guardarProductoEnFirestore(
        puerta: Puerta,
        formatoSeleccionado: String?,
        medidasHojaSeleccionadas: String?,
        medidasBlockSeleccionadas: String?,
        aperturaSeleccionada: String?
    ) {
        val producto = hashMapOf(
            "modelo" to puerta.modelo,
            "acabado" to puerta.acabado,
            "formato" to formatoSeleccionado,
            "medidasHoja" to medidasHojaSeleccionadas,
            "medidasBlock" to medidasBlockSeleccionadas,
            "apertura" to aperturaSeleccionada,
            "medidasGalces" to puerta.medidasGalces,
            "medidasTapajuntas" to puerta.medidasTapajuntas,
            "pernios" to puerta.pernios,
            "picaporte" to puerta.picaporte,
            "precio" to puerta.precio,
            "unidades" to puerta.unidades,
            "enCarrito" to true,
        )
        carritoCollection.add(producto)
            .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
                Log.d(TAG, "Producto guardado con ID: ${documentReference.id}")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.w(TAG, "Error al guardar el producto", e)
            }

    }
}
```

Now my adapter:

```
package com.example.puertasarseapp

import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class PuertasAdapter(puertasList: List<Puerta>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PuertasAdapter.PuertaViewHolder>() {

    private val puertasList = ArrayList<Puerta>()
    private var addToCartClickListener: OnAddToCartClickListener? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PuertaViewHolder {
        val itemView =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_puerta, parent, false)
        return PuertaViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PuertaViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val puerta = puertasList[position]
        holder.configurePuerta(puerta)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return puertasList.size
    }

    fun actualizarPuertas(puertas: List<Puerta>) {
        puertasList.clear()
        puertasList.addAll(puertas)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun setOnAddToCartClickListener(listener: OnAddToCartClickListener) {
        addToCartClickListener = listener
    }

    inner class PuertaViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private var formatoSeleccionado: String? = null
        private var medidasHojaSeleccionadas: String? = null
        private var medidasBlockSeleccionadas: String? = null
        private var aperturaSeleccionada: String? = null
        val unidadesEditText = itemView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.unidadesSeleccionadas)

        init {
            unidadesEditText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(
                    s: CharSequence?,
                    start: Int,
                    count: Int,
                    after: Int
                ) {
                }

                override fun onTextChanged(
                    s: CharSequence?,
                    start: Int,
                    before: Int,
                    count: Int
                ) {
                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                    puertasList[adapterPosition].unidades = s.toString()
                }
            })
        }

        fun configurePuerta(puerta: Puerta) {
            puerta.modelo = "Nogal Nórdico"
            puerta.acabado = "Melamina"
            puerta.medidasGalces = "7 x 2,5"
            puerta.medidasTapajuntas = "2,20 x 7 x 1"
            puerta.pernios = "3"
            puerta.picaporte = "Picaporte de 47"
            puerta.unidades = unidadesEditText.text.toString()
            puerta.precio = "155.99"

            val enviarAlCarritoBtn = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.enviarAlCarritoBtn)
            enviarAlCarritoBtn.setOnClickListener {
                addToCartClickListener?.onAddToCartClick(
                    puerta,
                    formatoSeleccionado,
                    medidasHojaSeleccionadas,
                    medidasBlockSeleccionadas,
                    aperturaSeleccionada
                )
            }

            val formatoSpinner = itemView.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.formatoSpinner)
            val formatoOptions = arrayOf("", "Pta. lisa", "Pta. con 3 rayas")

            val adapterFormato =
                ArrayAdapter(itemView.context, R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item, formatoOptions)
            adapterFormato.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            formatoSpinner.adapter = adapterFormato

            formatoSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                    view: View?,
                    position: Int,
                    id: Long
                ) {
                    formatoSeleccionado = formatoOptions[position]
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                    formatoSeleccionado = null
                }
            }

            val medidasHojaSpinner = itemView.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.MedidasHojaSpinner)
            val medidasHojaOptions =
                arrayOf("", "2,03 x 62,5 x 3,5", "2,03 x 72,5 x 3,5", "2,03 x 82,5 x 3,5")
            val medidasBlockTextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewMedidasBlock)


            val adapterMedidasHoja =
                ArrayAdapter(itemView.context, R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item, medidasHojaOptions)
            adapterMedidasHoja.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            medidasHojaSpinner.adapter = adapterMedidasHoja

            medidasHojaSpinner.onItemSelectedListener =
                object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                    override fun onItemSelected(
                        parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                        view: View?,
                        position: Int,
                        id: Long
                    ) {
                        medidasHojaSeleccionadas = medidasHojaOptions[position]
                        medidasBlockSeleccionadas =
                            getMedidasBlockFromMedidasHoja(medidasHojaSeleccionadas)

                        if (medidasBlockSeleccionadas != null) {
                            medidasBlockTextView.text = "Medidas Block: $medidasBlockSeleccionadas"
                        } else {
                            medidasBlockTextView.text = "Medidas Block: "
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                        medidasHojaSeleccionadas = null
                        medidasBlockSeleccionadas = null

                        medidasBlockTextView.text = "Medidas Block: "
                    }
                }

            val aperturaSpinner = itemView.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.aperturaSpinner)
            val aperturaOptions = arrayOf("", "Izquierda", "Derecha")

            val adapterApertura =
                ArrayAdapter(itemView.context, R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item, aperturaOptions)
            adapterApertura.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            aperturaSpinner.adapter = adapterApertura

            aperturaSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                    view: View?,
                    position: Int,
                    id: Long
                ) {
                    aperturaSeleccionada = aperturaOptions[position]
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                    aperturaSeleccionada = null
                }
            }
        }

        private fun getMedidasBlockFromMedidasHoja(medidasHoja: String?): String? {
            return when (medidasHoja) {
                "2,03 x 62,5 x 3,5" -> "2,06 x 65 x 3,5"
                "2,03 x 72,5 x 3,5" -> "2,06 x 75 x 3,5"
                "2,03 x 82,5 x 3,5" -> "2,06 x 85 x 3,5"
                else -> null
            }
        }
    }

    interface OnAddToCartClickListener {
        fun onAddToCartClick(
            puerta: Puerta,
            formatoSeleccionado: String?,
            medidasHojaSeleccionadas: String?,
            medidasBlockSeleccionadas: String?,
            aperturaSeleccionada: String?
        )
    }
}
```

This is my Puerta class:

```
class Puerta {
    var modelo: String = ""
    var acabado: String = ""
    var medidasGalces: String = ""
    var medidasTapajuntas: String = ""
    var pernios: String = ""
    var picaporte: String = ""
    var precio: String = ""
    var unidades: String = ""
}
```

package com.example.puertasarseapp

This how my catalogue lyout looks:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGtG1.png)

Now I want to add a similar door in the same lyout, but I dont know what should I change in adapter or in my code.

Hope you can help me

I am trying to add new models to my catalog, but these are similar and I want them to have the same functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you looking for an adapter class that can be used for multiple types of objects?